# Can't enable/disable publishing features on a meeting workspace

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, publishing, meeting-workspace, template

I'm trying to save a meeting workspace as a template. However, on this client's server, upgrade happened, so I got Pages library IDs messed up. I managed to fix that issue everywhere else on the farm, except on the meeting workspace.

Problem is, I'm getting this exception although meeting workspace does not have Pages library at all.

> Provisioning did not succeed. Details: Failed to create the 'Pages'
>   library. Ori ginalException: The feature failed to activate because a
>   list at 'Pages' already  exists in this site.  Delete or rename the
>   list and try activating the feature again.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself.

Apparently Meeting Workspaces do have pages library but it's hidden from browser. I followed first part of [this](http://himanisharma.blogspot.com/2009/06/new-pages-added-to-meeting-workspace-do.html) tutorial and found/deleted the library, and then I activated publishing features from powershell with no problem.

```
stsadm -o activatefeature -name PublishingWeb -url https://UrlOfPublishingSite 

iisreset
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to rename the hidden Pages library in SPD, then enable publishing.